# download file on the user's side

Tags: c#, .net, pdf, download, webclient

I'm looking for a way to save the file to the user's files
directory

I convert html to pdf, and save pdf to temporary file

```
    string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetTempPath() + id.ToString() + ".pdf";
    await page.PdfAsync(fileName)
```

Here I try download file (.pdf) on the user's site

```
    var client = new WebClient();
    client.DownloadFile(fileName, $"{id}.pdf");
```

but I think it save to the server
nothing on the user's side when the app is published is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want allow the person who will use the application to download the file:

u can use https://github.com/hardkoded/puppeteer-sharp to convert html to .pdf in Stream format

**ServiceController**

```
public async Task<Stream> BytesStreamWord(string html)
  { 
    await using var browser = await Puppeteer.LaunchAsync(new LaunchOptions { Headless = true });
    await using var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
    await page.SetContentAsync(html);
    var result = await page.GetContentAsync();

    Stream bytesStream = await page.PdfStreamAsync();

   return bytesStream;
}
```

and use return File() in method

**ExportController**

```
    return File(bytesStream, "application/pdf", "sampleName.pdf");
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use the class KnownFolders from here

https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/878605/Getting-All-Special-Folders-in-NET

and then on the client side make something like that

```
var client = new WebClient();
client.DownloadFile(fileName, Path.Combine(KnownFolders.GetPath(KnownFolder.Downloads), $"{id}.pdf"));
```